# How to use generics to handle defined operations on objects of different classes with common super class and its collections without casting?

Tags: java, generics

Lets have super class `ProxyHost` and extending classes `HttpProxyHost`, `HttpsProxyHosts`, `Socks4ProxyHost`, `Socks5ProxyHost`

Lets have couple collections on those concreet classes:

```
private ArrayList<HttpsProxyHost> httpsProxies = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Socks5ProxyHost> socks5Proxies = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<HttpProxyHost> httpProxies = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Socks4ProxyHost> socks4Proxies = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now what I want is to do something like that (2 variants below, both failing):

```
    private <T extends ProxyHost> void processRow(Element row, T h, ArrayList<T> httpProxies) {
        h.setIp("someIp");
        h.setOrigin("Some origin");
        h.setPort(1234);
        httpProxies.add(h);
    }

//some other part of app:
    ArrayList<? super ProxyHost> list;
            ProxyHost proxy;
            switch (type) {
            case "HTTP":
                proxy = new HttpProxyHost();
                processRow(row,proxy,httpProxies); // argument missmatch
                break;
            case "HTTPS":
                proxy = new HttpsProxyHost();
                processRow(row,proxy,httpsProxies); //argument missmatch
                break;
            case "SOCKS4":
                list = socks4Proxies; //lists type mismatch
                proxy = new Socks4ProxyHost();
                break;
            case "SOCKS5":
                list = socks5Proxies; //lists type mismatch
                proxy = new Socks5ProxyHost();
                break;
}
```

So the thing is, that in order to keept that piece of code DRY before adding to concreet collections I want to perform some common operations. 
How to do that using generics without using supertype and explicit casting? Is there a way?

Every time I think I understand generic collections, after shor time I find that I actually dont ;(

**EDIT:** I came out with the most elegant solution I can think of for now:

```
private <T extends ProxyHost> void processRow(Element row, T h, List<T> list) {
    h.setIp(row.child(0).text());
    h.setPort(Integer.parseInt(row.child(1).text()));
    h.setOrigin("SomeOrigin");
    list.add(h);
}
//and calls:
processRow(row, new HttpProxyHost(), httpProxies);
processRow(row, new HttpsProxyHost(), httpsProxies);
//etc works like charm now
```

Comment: There are at least two issues here: (1) you're trying to have compile-time checking cover something that is only known at runtime (hence the argument mismatches).  (2) I'm pretty sure that should be `ArrayList<? extends ProxyHost> list;`.

Comment: What is the type of `httpProxies` and `httpsProxies`?

Comment: @JornVernee They are `List` objects, listed in the first code block.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still half asleep

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth ah `super` wildcaard did sneak in there indeed. Thus I would thing that this is perfect for PECS as in this context I only want to add(thus from list POV to consume) to the collections. I wont be able to add in case `extends`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I always thought of `<T extends Base>` that is is guaranteed that T is constant in current execution context thus call to `<T extends Base> method(T t,List<T> list)` should be fine as list is declared to contain the exact same type as argument `t` with the additional extra info that this type must extends `Base` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for `processRow(row,proxy,httpProxies)` to work, `T` must resolve to `HttpProxyHost`, otherwise parameter `ArrayList<T> httpProxies` will not be compatible with `httpProxies` value of type `ArrayList<HttpProxyHost>`.

However, if `T` is `HttpProxyHost`, then parameter `T h` requires a `HttpProxyHost`, but the value is given as `proxy` of type `ProxyHost`, even though it actually holds an object of type `HttpProxyHost`.

By assigning `new HttpProxyHost()` to `ProxyHost proxy`, you lost the compatibility needed for the call to work.

You need:

```
case "HTTP": {
    HttpProxyHost httpProxy = new HttpProxyHost();
    processRow(row, httpProxy, httpProxies);
    proxy = httpProxy;
    break;
}
```

Comment: So in general - what I want to do in (IMHO) elegant way, is not possible without casting, did I get you right?

Comment: No but this can be replaced with `proxy=new HttpProxyHost(); ` processRow(row, (HttpProxyHost)proxy, httpProxies);`. This are equivalent without extra assignement

Comment: But bypasses compiler type-checking, so it's a bad idea if avoidable, which it is.